# Uploading file to Google Drive Via Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

Referred: https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/
Step 1) https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/quickstart.html#authentication
Created “client_secrets.json” in the local fs working directory.

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
```

**Error**:
InvalidClientSecretsError                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py in LoadClientConfigFile(self, client_config_file)
385     try:
--> 386       client_type, client_info = clientsecrets.loadfile(client_config_file)
387     except clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError as error:
.....
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydrive**/auth.py** in LoadClientConfigFile(self, client_config_file)
386       client_type, client_info = clientsecrets.loadfile(client_config_file)
387     except clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError as error:
--> 388       raise InvalidConfigError('Invalid client secrets file %s' % error)
389     if not client_type in (clientsecrets.TYPE_WEB,
390                            clientsecrets.TYPE_INSTALLED):

**InvalidConfigError: Invalid client secrets file Missing property "redirect_uris" in a client type of "web"**.

**Tried**

```
gauth = GoogleAuth()
credential_file = 'client_secrets.json' 
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile(credential_file)
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
gauth.SaveCredentialsFile(credential_file)
```

**Error**
**KeyError**                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
2 credential_file = 'client_secrets.json' #'../input/gdriveauth/client_secret_259511041847-no6nt8ennhbccaoqhv98ucsccv3hglu7.apps.googleusercontent.com.json'
3 #gauth.LoadCredentialsFile(credential_file)
---**-> 4 gauth.LoadCredentialsFile(credential_file)** ...

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/**client.py** in new_from_json(cls, json_data)
300         # Find and call the right classmethod from_json() to restore
301         # the object.
--> 302         module_name = data['_module']
303         try:
304             module_obj = **import**(module_name)

**KeyError: '_module'**

Answer (score 0):

You created and downloaded the incorrect type of credentials file.

Where you create your credentials at [console.cloud.google.com](https://console.cloud.google.com) you need to choose an application type of 'Desktop' not 'Web'.